# Caffeine cache - put in the cache keys for values unreachable in the database?

Tags: java, caffeine-cache

my Caffeine cache works perfectly.
But, i would like to improve its performances.

In fact, many of keys i want to load from my cache are not in the database.
Is there a way that Caffeine put all theses unreachable keys in the map,
so that when i request again to the Caffeine cache, caffeine does NOT REQUEST AGAIN to the database ?

exemple :

```
  key FR12333 : exist in DB ==> is put in the cache as ("FR12333","something")

  key FR76663 : exist in DB ==> is put in the cache as ("FR76663","something")

  key FR88888 : DO NOT exist in DB ==> is put in the cache as ("FR88888",null)
```

is there a way/option to do that ?

Comment: You can use negative caching, e.g. where the value is an `Optional`. That way the cache maintains an entry indicating its absence in the data store.

Comment: @BenManes absoluty correct ! works perfectly using Optional as Object Wrapper. many thanks.